# SQL Like Operator from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How to write a sql query with like operator from two different tables? I have written query like below, but didn't worked out.

select A.Username,A.User_descr,B.Request,B.CREATED_DATE,B.MODIFIED_DATE from TEMP_CPERF A,SERVICE B
where A.User_id=B.User_id and B.REQUEST like '%' + A.PERF_ID + '%';

In Table B, Request column is CLOB and am using Table A's PERF_ID column to retrieve data. It is giving me Invalid Number Error.

Comment: In SQL `+` is the mathematical plus. The concatenation operator is `||`.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation operator is double pipe `||` character, not `+`.

So:

```
SELECT a.username,
       a.user_descr,
       b.request,
       b.created_date,
       b.modified_date
  FROM temp_cperf a, service b
 WHERE     a.user_id = b.user_id
       AND b.request LIKE '%' || a.perf_id || '%';
```

Comment: It worked.. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome.